# android anyconnect to cisco 3800

Tags: vpn, cisco, android, anyconnect

I have a Cisco 3800 with Advanced IP Services running version 12.4(13r). For a client to VPN in using AnyConnect, it looks like I use the webvpn config options (SSL VPN). I followed one of the tutorials (e.g. [cisco ssl vpn](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/iosswrel/ps6537/ps6586/ps6657/prod_white_paper0900aecd8051ac50.html)). Is this the same setup to allow connections from the AnyConnect app on Android devices? Do I need a separate license? Newer version of IOS? I get an error when trying to connect with the Android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a separate license to enable mobile device connectivity.  This license is available only on the ASA firewall platform - license SKU L-ASA-AC-M-55XX=.  At this time there is no capability to connect Mobile devices like android to an ISR router.